# VBA Coding to extract data from .txt file

Tags: excel, vba

i tried to extract data from .txt file as per attached using below coding. However, i don't have idea how to remain the negative value as when i run the coding, the negative sign will missing. Please help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtYFB.png)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String, Point1 As Integer, LastRow As Long, Filename As String, x As Variant

'Open File Location
myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()

'Read the data file
Open myFile For Input As #1

Do Until EOF(1)
Line Input #1, textline
text = text & textline

Loop

Close #1 'Close data file

'Defined starting point
 Point1 = InStr(text, "Coord. Z")

'Adding new line
LastRow = Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'Get Module S/N from filename
strFilePath = myFile
Filename = Replace(Dir([strFilePath]), ".txt", "")

'Location of the data
Sheet2.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = Filename
Sheet2.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = Mid(text, Point1 + 21, 8)
Sheet2.Range("C" & LastRow).Value = Mid(text, Point1 + 36, 8)
Sheet2.Range("D" & LastRow).Value = Mid(text, Point1 + 54, 8)
Sheet2.Range("E" & LastRow).Value = Mid(text, Point1 + 70, 8)
Sheet2.Range("F" & LastRow).Value = Mid(text, Point1 + 84, 8)
Sheet2.Range("G" & LastRow).Value = Mid(text, Point1 + 103, 8)

`End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the text file contains only one line with Coord. Z and the values are separated by spaces you can also scan for that line and split to an array using the following code;

```
Dim vTmp as variant
Dim i as long, j as long

Do Until EOF(1)
Line Input #1, textline
If InStr(text, "Coord. Z") then vTmp = split(textline, " ")
Loop
```

This code makes an array vTmp which contains concatinated characters (or empty entries if double spaces are present)

Next loop through the resulting array and dump the values in your sheet.

```
j = 1 'Start column

'Loop through array
For i = LBound(vTmp) to UBound(vTmp)
    If vTmp(i) <> "" 'If entry is not empty
        Sheet2.Cells(LastRow, j).value = vTmp(i) 'Dump entry
        j = j + 1 'Next column
    End if
Next i
```